# How to properly define arguments to use in triangulatePoints (opencv)?

Tags: c++, opencv, triangulation

I try to use triangulatePoints from opencv but I think I do something wrong (I read one of the question about triangulatePoints on stackoverflow but not everything I understand). Assume that I have one point coords - pt1 and pt2 that correspond to coordinates of one point in left and right camera. Pt1 and pt2 is cv::Point.

So I have:

```
cv::Mat cam0(3, 4, CV_64F, k_data1)   //k_data1 is [R|t] 3x4 matrix for left camera
cv::Mat cam1(3, 4, CV_64F, k_data2)   //k_data2 is [R|t] 3x4 matrix for right camera
cv::Point pt1;                        //for left camera
cv::Point pt2                         //for right camera
```

I also define

```
cv::Mat pnt3D(1, 1, CV_64FC4).
```

And my question is how to properly define this two points (cv::Point)? 
I have tried to do this:

```
cv::Mat_<cv::Point> cam0pnts;
cam0pnts.at<cv::Point>(0) = pt1;
cv::Mat_<cv::Point> cam1pnts;
cam1pnts.at<cv::Point>(0) = pt2;
```

But app throws some exceptions, so maybe I do something wrong.

### **EDIT:**

Ok, with some help from @Optimus 1072 I corrected some lines of code and I get something like this:

```
double pCam0[16], pCam1[16];

cv::Point pt1 = m_history.getPoint(0);
cv::Point pt2 = m_history.getPoint(1);
m_cam1.GetOpenglProjectionMatrix(pCam0, 640, 480);
m_cam2.GetOpenglProjectionMatrix(pCam1, 640, 480);
cv::Mat cam0(3, 4, CV_64F, pCam0); 
cv::Mat cam1(3, 4, CV_64F, pCam1); 

vector<cv::Point2f> pt1Vec;
vector<cv::Point2f> pt2Vec;
pt1Vec.push_back(pt1);
pt2Vec.push_back(pt2);

cv::Mat pnt3D(1,1, CV_64FC4);

cv::triangulatePoints(cam0, cam1, pt1Vec, pt2Vec, pnt3D);
```

But still I get an exception:

> ...opencv\opencv-2.4.0\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\triangulate.cpp:75: error: (-209) Number of proj points coordinates must be == 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this works:

```
cv::Mat pointsMat1(2, 1, CV_64F);
cv::Mat pointsMat2(2, 1, CV_64F);

int size0 = m_history.getHistorySize();

for(int i = 0; i < size0; i++)
{
  cv::Point pt1 = m_history.getOriginalPoint(0, i);
  cv::Point pt2 = m_history.getOriginalPoint(1, i);

  pointsMat1.at<double>(0,0) = pt1.x;
  pointsMat1.at<double>(1,0) = pt1.y;
  pointsMat2.at<double>(0,0) = pt2.x;
  pointsMat2.at<double>(1,0) = pt2.y;

  cv::Mat pnts3D(4, 1, CV_64F);

  cv::triangulatePoints(m_projectionMat1, m_projectionMat2, pointsMat1, pointsMat2, pnts3D);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way is two form a vector of 2-D points like this

```
vector<Point2f> pt1;
vector<Point2f> pt2;
```

and then You can insert points in this vector like

```
Point p;
p.x = x;
p.y = y;
pt1.push_back(p);
```

Comment: I still get an exception: _...opencv\opencv-2.4.0\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\triangulate.cpp:75: error: (-209) Number of proj points coordinates must be == 2_ Maybe that error depends on something else. I will write all code from my method soon, maybe someone can help

Comment: My intuition says the problem is in the line `cv::Point pt1 = m_history.getPoint(0);` . But I am not sure please post the whole code.

Comment: One more method would be to use a 2 channel matrix of N elements  something like this `Mat c_pts1(1,N,CV_64FC2);` ans shouldn't be pnt3D be some thing like this `cv::Mat pnt3D(1,**N**, CV_64FC4);
`

Comment: Certainly problem is not in the line with 'cv::Point pt1 = m_history.getPoint(0);' because I get exception only when line 'cv::triangulatePoints(cam0, cam1, pt1Vec, pt2Vec, pnt3D);' is uncommented.

Comment: If "N" could be equal to 1?

Comment: if I do like you wrote and ` c_pts(1, 1, CV_64FC2, projPtsArray) ` I get _error: (-209) Number of proj points coordinates must be == 2_

Comment: it should work can you please post whole code of yours

Comment: Now it works, there was second problem in other part of my code.